# How can I setup a React-native comment system properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

So I'm pretty new to `React-native` & am building an `article feed` which allows people to comment & view comments on each `article`. At the moment I'm able to render the comments just fine but I'm unsure how I can make the component `render` a comment that the user has just submitted.

I've got it setup so when the user adds a comment, It's sent to an `API` call which then recieves a `JSON` object in return of that comment. I then save that comment in my `redux store (reducer)` under `newcomment`. But each time I add a new comment My whole Feed of articles seems to re-render & that comment is posted on every `articlecomponent`.

Below is my render() function for a single `ArticleComponent`:

This part here loops through the comments for the particular article & renders each single comment. Further down in my code I then put this in my `return(` statement.

```
// If first 5 comments from article exist... (5 can change to maybe 10?)
    if(comments){
      var commentsRendered = comments.map(function(comment, key){
        return <CommentComponent comment={comment} key={key}/>
      });
    }
```

Here is my return statement. Inside here I printout the `commentsRendered` array of comoponents

```
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} key={Math.random()}>
        <Text>{ user } posted something</Text>
        <Text>{ articleText }</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={
            (text) => this.setState({comment: text})
          }
          value={this.state.comment} />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ this._postComment.bind(this, articleid) }>
          <Text  style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
            Submit
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        {
          (comments) &&
            <View>{ commentsRendered }</View>
        }
        { 
          /* This should only print out on ONE article & not all */
          (this.props.newcomment) &&
            <View><CommentComponent comment={this.comment.comment} key={Math.random()}/></View>

        }

      </View>
    )
```

Inside the return I'm checking to see if the comment that was just submitted is in the redux store yet. If it's in the redux store I then render it using the `CommentComponent`. But for some reason when the redux store is updated with the new comment & following is rendered ->

```
(this.props.newcomment) &&
                <View><CommentComponent comment={this.comment.comment} key={Math.random()}/></View>
```

It seems to render the comment on all `ArticleComponents` & not the specific one that the comment was submitted to. If you submit one comment & then submit another it replaces the first comment you made.

Am I going about this wrong? Or am I not doing something right?

Just something to add - If there are any react-native/redux examples of `comment` sections that would help me with this problem, it would be good if you could link them so I could get an idea of what other people have done.

Comment: How did you handle this?